# Generate request xml from wsdl in node.js

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a Node js app which will call SOAP services.
I need to generate the request xml for a service url provided at runtime.
Is that possible?

Edit 1:
The basic idea is to sort of replicate what SOAP UI does when you create a new SOAP project.
Basically, get the sample request XMLs of all the operations in the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

misread that part. usually when someone send me a wsdl url, there will be another link that ends with ?singleWsdl. in that file, there are schemas for all the requests, responses of every available methods. Eg abc.com/myservice.svc?wsdl and abc.com/myservice.svc?singleWsdl

it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Sending an xml request is not the problem. I want to generate and print the sample request at run time like SOAP UI does.

Comment: I misread that part. usually when someone send me a wsdl url, there will be another link that ends with `?singleWsdl`. in that file, there are schemas for all the requests, responses of every available methods. Eg `abc.com/myservice.svc?wsdl` and `abc.com/myservice.svc?singleWsdl`